# Overflow table on to next page while leaving room at the top

Tags: css, netsuite, bfo

I am building an Advanced HTML/PDF Template in NetSuite to be a check with voucher (check on top). Everything works well until the number of voucher items overflows on to the next page. The table logically resumes at the top of the subsequent page. But because of the check stock we are using, it would ideally resume 1/3 of the way down the page on the next "stub" section.

If I was only printing 1 check at time, I could use a header that doesn't apply to page 1 to push things down on page 2 and be good. But when multiple checks are printed at once, this doesn't work.

I also attempted to add a large, blank thead row on the voucher table to push the table down when it resumes on page 2. The check itself is absolutely positioned on the page. So I also was planning to absolutely position the voucher table so they overlap on page 1 and the proper space is created on page 2. But this did not work because I can't make the table absolutely positioned.

`<body> kid can't be absolute: Ignoring <table class=[...`

I'm guessing there is likely a simple solution or otherwise creative workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting the page number on the page break for each individual check ended up being my answer.

`<pbr pagenumber="1" />`

https://bfo.com/products/report/docs/tags/tags/pbr.html

```
        <style>
            #page2,
            #page3,
            #page4 {
                header: blankheader;
                header-height: 260pt;
            }
        </style>

        <macrolist>
            <macro id="blankheader">
                <div />
            </macro>
        </macrolist>
```